# When importing memberships, I get "Error: Invalid value for field(s) : Start Date; End date"

Tags: civimember, import

I hope someone can answer this!
I've tried 30 various date formats, rearranged columns, and every time I do a membership import it fAils. No errors are presented, I'm just returned to "Upload Data (step 1 of 4)" from step 3... I never see step 4 (summary).
In "plugins/files/civicrm/upload" folder I see a file "sqlImport.errors" which shows an error not recognizing the date formate for the membership start and end

But I've tried every format and none work. :(.

Each time one membership record (1 row) imports, and then if fails! Every time.

The first 2,5 lines of sqlImport.errors says:

Line Number","Reason","External Identifier (match to contact)","Membership Type Id","Email (match to contact)","Membership Start Date","Membership Expiration Date"
"2","Invalid value for field(s) : Start Date; End date","33","Adult","wfsdfoks@telus.net","06/01/2013","06/01/2014"
"3","Invalid value for field(s) : Start Date; End date","34","Youth","helsdfng@rebalasdftouch.com","06/01/2013","06/01/2015"

I've tried different formats of dates (yyyy-mm-dd, mm/dd/yy, mm/dd/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy) and selected the appropriate format from Step 1 in the import page.

Every time it's the same:
- I get to Step 3, and click "Submit"
- 1 (one, only) row get imported (correctly) and then
- I'm taken back to Step 1 - No error, complaint, nothing.

In my server's error log I see:

...client denied by server configuration: /home/civicthe/public_html/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom/delete-this-OcxGgONTcR 
... client denied by server configuration: /home/civicthe/public_html/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/upload/delete-this-Zj1bvAyuTv
...client denied by server configuration: /home/civicthe/public_html/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.fee2178658acc8deae2211eadc328c3b.log

FYI, after each fail (1 row imports) I delete the top row from the .csv file and try again, and again 1 row imports, so it can't be the .csv file.

Can anyone help? This is driving me bonkers.  Why does it fail if the next time I run the

Comment: The extra punctuation and allcaps are a turn-off. You'll have more success getting volunteer feedback with polite, civil language in your post.

Comment: hehe thanks Joe. Mama said always chill out before posting questions to frustrating situations... I should have calmed down first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using WPSec or some other security related wordpress plugins? Check:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-better-wp-security-client-denied-by-server-configuration

Seems like:

a. CiviCRM is trying to write something to the log file

b. The security plugin traps that and redirects you back to step 1

try disabling the plugins and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but no, we aren't using any extra security plugins. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you disable all WP plugins except for civicrm and try. The error is being issued by some code within your WP + plugin codebase most likely

Comment: Thanks everyone. the issue was indeed the JetPack plugin - once I disabled the "Notify" piece of that plugin the imports ran smoothly. Anyone know why Notify is causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

What you pasted is hard to read, but I **think** there is an issue of mixing of column and semi-column. At least it's a problem I've already experienced: the separator isn't correct and so it concatenates too many columns as if it were a single one

What column separator have you selected?

**Administer > Localization > Language, currency, location**

(Import / Export Field Separator)

Check that it matches your csv (edit it under notepad to be sure)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but nope - I'm using commas and have confirmed there are no extra comments in the small file I've been testing with. :-(